# Get the number of the line, from response, that matches the query

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query:

```
-- Top 3 users

SELECT
TOP (3) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [UserId], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Consider that the query above returns the following result:

```
UserId | Reputation
-------------------
33     | 93123
21     | 20301
40     | 20101
```

How can I get the line number where the user with id `40` appears? In the example above, it's `3`.

Also, I need to use it in another SQL query. How can I do that?

Comment: Umm... didn't you just query the row number as your first column? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Mureinik That would be better. How can I do that?

Comment: You're selecting `ROW_NUMBER()` anyway - just give it a sensible alias - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [rn]` - or am completely missing the question?

Comment: @Mureinik I need something like *row number* `WHERE Id = 40`. Then, that row number should be used in another query. Something like: "Position <row number> of <count>".

Comment: You have labelled the question MySQL, yet it uses SQL Server syntax.  What is the real database you are using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I was playing with http://data.stackexchange.com/ queries.

Comment: Then SQL Server would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways.  The first uses your subquery basically as a subquery:

```
SELECT seqnum
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS seqnum, 
             Id AS [UserId], 
             Reputation
      FROM Users
     ) u
WHERE UserId = 40;
```

The second just does the calculation using standard SQL:

```
select 1 + COUNT(*)
from Users u join
     Users u40
     on u.Reputation < u40.reputation and
        u40.Id = 40;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `id = 40` be `Id = 40`? In both cases (`id = 40` and `Id = 40`) I get `Invalid column name '...'.` error.

Comment: @IonicãBizãu . .  I missed the `Id` gets renamed in the first query.